# Передача параметров внутри шаблона jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

Подскажите, как внутри шаблона `jinja` реализовать следующую логику:

Есть цикл, внутри него, при помощи `loop.cycle` раздаётся класс `active` между элементами списка `ul`

Этих `<li> </li>` столько, сколько картинок в списке.

```
{% for image in images %} 
        <li class="{{ loop.cycle('active', '') }}">
            <a href="single-product.html#thumbnail_{{index+1}}"data-toggle="tab"><img src="{{image}}" alt="pro-thumbnail" /></a>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Вот блок (вне цикла), куда я хочу передать `{{image}}` того `<li>` класс которого `="active"`

```
<div class="single-product-image">
    <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{product.title}}" />
        <a class="new-mark-box" href="{{url_for('shop.single_product',keyword=product.id) }}">new</a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="{{image}}" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><span class="btn large-btn">View larger <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span></a>
                                        </div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при смене `class="active"` в `<li> </li>`, в верхнем блоке менялся `{{image}} (ссылка на картинку)`

Я могу объявить `{{image}}` до цикла при помощи `{% set %}`, но как реализовать динамику?

Comment: не ясно, что куда вы хотите передать. Приведите для примера входной `images`  список и соответствующий желаемый html результат (уберите всё что не относится к проблеме напрямую).

Comment: Желаемый результат - изменение {{image}} у стоящего вне цикла элемента, при изменении class="active" у элемента из списка

Comment: Всё равно слишком неподробно, допишите в вопрос что jfs попросил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается при помощи передачи `{{loop.index}}`, однако, само взаимодействие блоков происходит благодаря js.

```
<div class="single-product-view">

    <div class="tab-content">
    {% for image in images %}
        <div class="tab-pane {% if  loop.first  %} {{'active'}} {% endif %}" id="thumbnail_{{loop.index}}">
            <div class="single-product-image">
                <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{product.title}}" />
                <a class="new-mark-box" href="{{ url_for('shop.single_product',keyword=product.id) }}">new</a>
                <a class="fancybox" href="{{image}}" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><span class="btn large-btn">View larger <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
                                    </div>                                      
</div>
<div class="select-product">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs select-product-tab bxslider">
        {% for image in simages %}
        <li  class="{% if  loop.first  %} {{'active'}} {% endif %}">
            <a href="single-product.html#thumbnail_{{loop.index}}" data-toggle="tab"><img src="{{image}}" alt="{{product.title}}" /></a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все переменные которые создаются внутри цикла, находятся в его локальной области и передать их никуда нельзя. Либо необходимый тег надо ставить внутрь цикла, либо итерировать массив повторно в нужном месте.

Использовать любой шаблонизатор как язык программирования - это ахитектурная ошибка.

Лучше всего произвести необходимые манипуляции в контроллере, а в шаблон уже передать те данные, которые необходимы для отображения.