# Преобразование типов данных, или как указать питону, что строка - это список?

Tags: python, jinja2

Есть "строка" такого типа.

```
['https://m.sportowysklep.pl/media/wbthumb/2016/jordan/64321/buty-air-jordan-12-retro-bg-the-master-153265-013-573dba8b7b64f.jpg', 'https://m.sportowysklep.pl/media/wbthumb/2016/nike/67568/buty-air-jordan-12-retro-bg-flu-game-153265-002-574e89d68c3f5.jpg', 'https://m.sportowysklep.pl/media/wbthumb/2016/jordan/68519/buty-air-jordan-12-retro-bg-unc-153265-007-579f415fee419.jpg', 'https://m.sportowysklep.pl/media/wbthumb/2016/nike/69653/buty-air-jordan-12-retro-bg-gym-red-153265-600-579097ad76784.jpg']
```

По своему виду она является списком, но питон, а если быть точнее jinja, воспринимает это как строку.
Задача - получить урлы без ковычек и скобок.

`product.fullimage[2:-2]).split(',')` - вот так обрабатывать не вариант.

Answer (score 4):

Нет смысла преобразовывать строку в список, для того, чтобы убрать кавычки. Тем более, что кавычки только лишь показывают вам, что данный массив является строкой.

Из написанного вижу, что то что вы назвали строкой - на самом деле список, в котором расположены несколько адресов. Если же jinja воспринимает его как строку, то достаточно найти место где вы сами преобразовали ваш список в строку.

Любой адрес из вашего списка в jinja можно получить итерированием:

```
{% for my_url in my_list %}
    {{ my_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Другой вопрос в том, что жинжа может экранировать слэши(покрайней мере джанговский шаблонизатор экранирует), у ваших строк, поэтому нужно будет это учесть.

**Ну и по вопросу. Строка в список преобразовывается таким образом:**

```
my_list = list(my_string)
```

Comment: 1- `['[', "'", 'h', 't', 't', 'p', 's', ':', '/', '/', ..., 'j', 'p', 'g', "'", ']']`—это вероятно не тот список, который нужен автору вопроса. Строка в вопросе явно содержит константу, создающую Питон список (Python list literal), поэтому следует использовать `ast.literal_eval()` вместо `list()`. 2- Идея, что "строка" уже и так список (и поэтому ничего не надо преобразовывать) является хорошей, хотя [предыдущий вопрос автора](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567037/23044) явно содержит цикл, что может указывать на то, что автор знает о циклах в jinja (но повторить не вредно).

Comment: Предыдущий вопрос я уже потом прочитал. В строке вопроса констант я не вижу, но вижу, что он пытается убрать кавычки и разбить строку по запятым, тоесть получить нужные ему строки из списка. Подозреваю что он где-то, совершенно случайно, просто преобразовал этот список в строку. Но ведь выложил он его, в задаче, не как строку, а как список.

Comment: *"преобразовал этот список в строку"* —пункт номер один из моего ответа об этом (то есть я также думаю, что это одно из возможных объяснений). *"констант я не вижу"* —вы понимаете разницу между `ast.literal_eval("[]")` и `list("[]")`? В первом случае строка как константа (literal), задающая список интерпретируется.

Answer (score 3):

Два решения:

1. Найти место выше по течению, где список превращается в строку, и либо убрать это преобразование либо дать этому списку имя, которое позже можно использовать
2. Менее желательный вариант по сравнению с предыдущим пунктом: [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), но безопасней чем `eval()`. Избегайте вызыва `eval()` на вводе, который вы не контролируете.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас действительно список внутри строки, то можно сделать так:

```
my_list = eval(my_string)
```

Но eval - это очень скользкий путь.
А чем не устраивает вариант со split? Имхо, это самое естественное решение в данной ситуации.

Comment: `product.fullimage[2:-2]).split('\', \'')` - вот так работает, но мне кажется это не лучшей практикой.

Comment: Вы можете использовать двойные кавычки, чтобы обернуть одинарные - это позволит обойтись без экранирования слэшами:    .split("', '")

Comment: @Александр: как редактирование руками строки, содержащей текстовое представление Питон-списка, чтобы достать вложенные строки, так и вызов `eval()`, на строках неизвестного происхождения являются плохой идеей.

Comment: А почему вы считаете eval скользким путем? Хотя бы ОДИН пример в студию...

Comment: @Xyanight eval можно использовать только на входах, которые вы полностью контролируете, и про которые вы абсолютно уверены, что там будет корректный код. Если пропускать через eval строки, которые вводят другие пользователи, то любой пользователь потенциально может выполнить любой код на вашей стороне. Что просто ужас с точки зрения безопасности. Ну и любая некорректная строка в eval может уронить ваш скрипт.

Comment: То есть, по вашему утверждению, любой пользователь, имеющий достаточно знаний в программировании, может сгенерировать строку, которая выполнится eval!? А взять, и заменить, например, подключаемый программой модуль на СВОЙ со СВОИМ кодом не может (тем более, если речь идет о Python - скриптовом языке)? Все заявления об опасности eval БЕСПОЧВЕННЫ и НЕ ОБОСНОВАНЫ!

Comment: @Xyanight: Подумайте в каком контексте обычно используется jinja2 библиотека. Запустите сервис, который `eval()` делает и подумайте хотите ли вы сделать его доступным извне.

Answer (score 1):

fn1-re.split 
fn2-eval, 
fn3-literal_eval

Как видно, самый быстрый способ, через re.split

```
import timeit, re, ast, random
STR = "'https://m.sportowysklep.pl/media/wbthumb/2016/jordan/%s/b013-573dba8b7b64f.jpg'"
STR = " ,".join(STR % random.randrange(10000) for _ in range(1000))
STR = '[%s]' % STR


def fn1():
    def get():
        for v in re.split("[' , \[ \] ]", STR):
            if v: yield v
    return list(get())

def fn2():
    return eval(STR)

def fn3():
    return ast.literal_eval(STR)

def execTime(target_: list, repeat=1):
    target_[:] = [(fn.__name__, timeit.Timer(fn).timeit(repeat)) for fn in target_]
    for e, (n, tmt) in enumerate(sorted(target_, key=lambda r: r[1]), start=1):
        print("{}'time {} {}".format(e, n, tmt))

execTime([fn1, fn2, fn3], 500)
```

out:

```
1'time fn1 1.4746107138626618
2'time fn3 2.3419654155086693
3'time fn2 3.3087369523448684
```